# C equivalent of Python for setting corelimit

Tags: python, c

What would be C equivalent of the following Python code:

```
import resource
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_CORE, (-1, -1))
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent code in C would be using the [`setrlimit`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html) system call:

```
 struct rlimit lim = {-1, -1};

 if (setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, &lim) == -1)
 { /* error */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Limits-on-Resources.html

```
struct rlimit
```

This structure is used with getrlimit to receive limit values, and with setrlimit to specify limit values for a particular process and resource.

```
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct rlimit lim = {-1, -1};
if (setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, &lim) == -1) return EXIT_FAILURE;
```